# Get job average elapsed time

Tags: jcl, control-m

I need to get the average elapsed time for each job in Active Job Environment in order to produce a report.
I've tried to extract it from SMF records but I don't seem to get the right one. Also I've tried keystroke language but it's to slow! The job takes around 15min to collect all the data. I thought about using CTMJSA but since I only have examples to UPDATE and DELETE the statistics I thought it would be wiser not to use it.
There must be a file that loads the Statistics Screen and I'd like to ask if anyone knows which is it or how could I get that information.

Thank you!!

Comment: Does your shop use MXG to process the SMF data?

Comment: You are talking about Syncsort? If yes, It's going to be installed in the next two weeks. Depending on the dataset you are talking about and the desired information output, we use SORT or programs that do SMF Dump.

Comment: No, I refer to the product MXG from Merrill Consultants.  http://mxg.com/product_info/.  It's commonly used to process SMF data, and if you were using it I might be able to help.  I have no connection to the company.

Answer (score 1):

Ctmruninf is a better utility to use in this case. I use it on Unix to produce total numbers (via perl) but you should be able to adapt it to mainframe and get averages. To list everything between fixed dates do -

ctmruninf -list 20151101120101 20151109133301 -JOBNAME pdiscm005

Comment: That seems useful. If brief.

Comment: I'm not sure I can access mainframe data through Unix. That utility get only data from the Control-M Server and that does not get me Mainframe Statistics. Thank you.

Comment: That's what I intend, the Mainframe Statistics. Thank you anyways! :)